# Changing the settings file when using django and gunicorn together

Tags: python, django, gunicorn

I've deployed my Django project using [this tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-ubuntu-16-04) and it works fine.

Now I want to split the settings file and have multiple settings in development and production environments. I created a `settings` directory and added these files into the directory:

```
my_project/
    manage.py
    my_project/
       __init__.py
       urls.py
       wsgi.py
       settings/
           __init__.py
           base.py
           dev.py
           prod.py
```

The `base.py` is same as former `settings.py` (that was working fine). I imported `base.py` and added `DEBAG=False` and `ALLOWED_HOSTS` to `prod.py`.

How can I tell the gunicorn to run my application with `prod` settings?

The `gunicorn.service` file, based on the tutorial is like this:

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn daemon
After=network.target

[Service]
User=sammy
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/home/sammy/myproject
ExecStart=/home/sammy/myproject/myprojectenv/bin/gunicorn --access-logfile - --workers 3 --bind unix:/home/sammy/myproject/myproject.sock myproject.wsgi:application

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the `settings.pyc` file in the project directory. Removing that file, fixed the problem.

Answer (score 7):

You can set `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` environment variable for this, as mentioned [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/settings/#on-the-server-mod-wsgi).

So you can try to add something like:

```
Environment="DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=my_project.settings.prod"
```

to `[Service]` section.

Comment: I tried this line of code and it doesn't work. I got 502 error.

Comment: Does it work without this variable? Is there anything in gunicorn logs? Also, could you try to set `ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*',]` to allow all hosts (temporarily) and to check it it's not the reason?

Comment: I finally found out the reason. It was getting error, because there was a `settings.pyc` file in the project directory.

Comment: Great answer, this one should be the accepted. Still works on 2020